# How to Stop Background Music When The Game is Over?

Tags: unity, music

I am working on a 2D Angry Birds type Unity game. I Created Menu Scene and Level One Scene and all the required scripts are added. After adding background music to Level One, when the game is over and return to Menu I can't stop the music. The Menu scene has its own music and when the level one is over, it continues with its own music and gets mix with the menu scene music. I tried to add `Destroy()` function to level one GameObject but Level One music became silent after I restart with my menu scene. Here is my code for the attached music game object:

```
public class background_sound : MonoBehaviour {
    public static bool soundBreaker = false;

    public void Start () {
        if (!soundBreaker) {
            AudioSource myAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
            myAudio.Play ();
            DontDestroyOnLoad (myAudio);
            soundBreaker = true;
        }   
    }
}
```

And here is the Menu Script:

```
public class MenuScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public void StartGame () {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Level One");
    }
    ...
```

Here is the code that loads the Menu Scene..

```
public void GameOver() {
    musicObject.setActive(false);
    startCoroutine(restTime());
}

IEnumerator restTime() {    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class to:

```
public class background_sound : MonoBehaviour {
    public static bool soundBreaker = false;

    public AudioSource audio;
    public void Start () {
        if (!soundBreaker) {
            audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
            audio.Play ();

            soundBreaker = true;

            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        }   
    }

    public void StopPlaying(){
        audio.Stop(); // or audio.Pause();
    }

    public void StartPlaying(){
        audio.Play();
    }
}
```

In your `GameOver()` do:

```
musicObject.GetComponent<background_sound>().StopPlaying();
```

And a tip:
Don't name your classes with a lowercase character and don't add `_` to it. It's a bad programming practice. Change it to `BackgroundSound` or something and rename it's file too.

Comment: I added your code but when it is game over and reloads level 1,the music becomes silent

Comment: Because in your Level's `Start()` you must call `musicObject.GetComponent<background_sound>().StartPlaying();`

Comment: I added start playing in Level 1 Start() but as the ball is reloaded it repeated the music before scene one is over.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the DontdestroyOnLoad

Comment: When I remove don't destroy,the music will start from the beginning within the same scene when it reloads the ball.I added the don't destroy to continue the music in that scene Only but it continues through all scenes.

Comment: I see, edit your question with the code that loads the Menu scene

Comment: The code that loads the menu scene is the MenuScript which I put on the question.

Comment: That is the Code that Loads level1, i wanna see the code that Loads the menu